# Remove y part from the x part in formula in R

Tags: r, formula

I have list of 12 Dataframes. one Dataframe looks like below:

```
df12<-data.frame(a.Boston=c(8,8),a.Hartford=c(6,6),a.Denver=c(8,8),b.Boston_12=c(8,8),b.Denver_12=c(6,6))
```

df12:

```
   a.Boston a.Hartford a.Denver b.Boston_12 b.Denver_12
    1        8          6        8           8           6
    2        8          6        8           8           6
```

And I am trying to create formula for each dataframe. Code is given below 
for creating a formula:

```
myformula<-lapply(1:12, function(x) as.formula(paste(paste0("a.", df[['city']][1], " ~ "), 
                                                     paste(sprintf("`%s`", colnames(get(paste0("df",x)))), collapse="+")))
)
```

My formula contains y part in x also. For example:

**Formula10**:

```
a.Boston ~ a.Boston + a.Hartford + a.Denver + b.Boston_10 + b.Boston_11 + 
  b.Boston_12 + b.Denver_10 + b.Denver_11 + b.Denver_12
```

**Formula12:**

```
a.Boston ~ a.Boston + a.Hartford + a.Denver + b.Boston_12 + b.Denver_12
```

So, I want to remove y part from the x part in the formula.

Comment: But it is always not 1st value in the formula. Suppose, if formula is `a.Hartford ~ a.Boston + a.Hartford + a.Denver + b.Boston_12 + b.Denver_12`, then it will not work.

Comment: I am trying to remove y part from x, so in the above example, if `y=a.Boston`, then remove a.Boston from x (`=a.Boston + a.Hartford + a.Denver + b.Boston_12 + b.Denver_12`) and if `y=a.Hartford` then remove a.Hartford from x(`=a.Boston + a.Hartford + a.Denver + b.Boston_12 + b.Denver_12`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all.vars` will give you a list of names in a formula without duplicates. That way anything in the `x` part of the formula will not appear if it is also present in `y` part. Then you can use `reformulate` to create formula.

```
formula10 = a.Boston ~ a.Boston + a.Hartford + a.Denver + b.Boston_10 +
            b.Boston_11 + b.Boston_12 + b.Denver_10 + b.Denver_11 + b.Denver_12
reformulate(all.vars(formula10)[-1], all.vars(formula10)[1])
#a.Boston ~ a.Hartford + a.Denver + b.Boston_10 + b.Boston_11 + 
#    b.Boston_12 + b.Denver_10 + b.Denver_11 + b.Denver_12
```

Comment: I am getting character(0) in temp.